# How can I fix the namespace error when using classes within the app folder?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, facade

I am upgrading a legacy laravel application from Laravel 5 to 8 and ran into a brick wall. None of my service providers work, and I cannot figure out why.

Previous Structure

app
-->Services
------>Stripe

Within each service provider folder, I'd create three files like so:

1. Stripe.php
2. StripeFacade.php
3. StripeServiceProvider.php

within `stripe.php`

```
<?php

namespace app\Services\Stripe;


class Stripe
{

}

?>
```

within `StripeFacade.php`

```
<?php

namespace app\Services\Stripe;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class StripeFacade extends Facade
{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'Stripe';
    }
}
```

within `StripeServiceProvider.php`

```
<?php

namespace app\Services\Stripe;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class StripeServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('Stripe', function($app) {
            return new Stripe();
        });
    }
}
```

in my `Config/app.php` file, I'd register the service provider and facade like so:

```
'providers' => [
    app\Services\Stripe\StripeServiceProvider::class,
],

'aliases' => [
    'Stripe' => app\Services\Stripe\StripeFacade::class,
]
```

In my controller, I'd call the Stripe service as

```
use Stripe;

...

public function example(){
   $auth = Stripe::auth();
}
```

Then I'd get this error in the `Config/app.php` file

```
Class "app\Services\Stripe\StripeServiceProvider" not found
```

I tried adding the Services directory to my psr-4 and didn't seem to get any luck, even after dumping configs and autoload.

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Services\\": "app/Services",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
```

any help? :)

Comment: Try namespace `App` instead of `app`.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden tried that earlier. Did it again, but now the error is `Class "App\Services\Stripe\StripeServiceProvider" not found`

Comment: Run `composer du` in CLI after the name change.

Comment: Run composer dump-autoload in CLI

Comment: @josezenem the warning in the console is `Class App\Services\Stripe\StripeServiceProvider located in ./app/Services /Stripe/StripeServiceProvider.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.` the other Stripe files receive similar warnings.

Comment: @SupunSpera `Class "App\Services\Stripe\StripeServiceProvider" not found` this error persists as long as I'm trying to add it to the `providers` array in `Config/app.php` :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comment, you posted an error:

> Class App\Services\Stripe\StripeServiceProvider located in ./app/Services /Stripe/StripeServiceProvider.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.

I noticed an extra space in `./app/Services /Stripe`.

Perhaps you have created the `Services /` directory with a space at the end.

Some improvements are to rename `app\` to `App\` and remove the `"Services\\":` line from your `composer.json`. Run `composer dump-autoload` after these changes.

Comment: YOU ARE RIGHT! Major facepalm moment

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
 namespace App\Services\Stripe;

 use App\Services\Stripe\StripeServiceProvider::class
```

Comment: Where exactly am I supposed to use this?